# i would show a list<> in a windows form how i can do this ? with dataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I am creating a form that displays all the elements of the list and can not figure out how to do it

```
class Prestiti : List<OggettoPrestito>
    {

        public new int IndexOf(OggettoPrestito item)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++)
            {
                if (this[i].NumeroPrestito == item.NumeroPrestito)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
        public new void Add(OggettoPrestito item)
        {
            if (this.IndexOf(item) < 0)
            {
                base.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Prestito già inserito");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose one of the following default controls:

- `ListBox`, if the items can be represented by a single string (no columns)
- `ListView`, if you want the list to look like the folder/files view
- `DataGridView`, if you want a more excel-like view